# Mockito changing the default value for wrapper classes

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a bean that has an Integer property. The method I am testing checks to see if the initial value of that property is null, if it is it sets it. According to the mockito docs:

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...)

So my property is set to 0 by mockito and my test fails. Is there a way to override this default behavior?

**EDIT**

Jeff Bowman gave a great answer, and I would like to follow his advice... however I'm not sure how. Here is some of the method I am trying to test:

```
public class ViewBeanBuilder {

    @Inject
    private ViewBean viewBean;

    public void buildViewBean() {
        ....
        for (Model model : getModels()) {
            if (viewBean.getAmount() == null || model.getAmount() < viewBean.getAmount()) {
                    viewBean.setAmount(model.getAmount());
            }            

        }
        ....
    }

}
```

My problem is, if I don't mock the `ViewBean` then I get a null pointer exception. However, when I do mock it I have the problems already discussed. Am I taking the wrong approach? Is there another way to do this?

One thought I had was to put a getter around my viewBean:

```
public class ViewBeanBuilder {

    @Inject
    private ViewBean viewBean;

    public void buildViewBean() {
        ....
        for (Model model : getModels()) {
            if (getViewBean().getAmount() == null || model.getAmount() < getViewBean().getAmount()) {
                    viewBean.setAmount(model.getAmount());
            }            

        }
        ....
    }

    private ViewBean getViewBean() {
        return viewBean;
    }

}
```

Then in my test I could use:

```
@InjectMocks
private ViewBeanBuilder builder = new ViewBeanBuilder();    

@Test
private void testBuilder() {
    ViewBean viewBean = new ViewBean();
    when(builder.getViewBean()).thenReturn(viewBean);

    builder.buildViewBean();
    ....
}
```

I'll probably try this tomorrow. But is this a valid approach?

**EDIT**

Using the when also failed...

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code?  Both the method you are trying to test / mock and the mockito code to test it... please...

Answer (score 5):

First of all, *don't mock data objects* (objects that contain significant state). Beans are data objects. Instead, create a real bean, put values into it, and use that bean in your tests.

That said, Mockito mocks have no implementation, and do not behave differently between bean methods and other methods:

```
YourBean bean = Mockito.mock(YourBean.class);  // A mock acting like YourBean.
bean.getIntegerValue();                        // Returns 0 by default.
bean.setIntegerValue(50);                      //
bean.getIntegerValue();                        // Still returns 0, not 50.

                                               // The call to setIntegerValue is
verify(bean).setIntegerValue(50);              // recorded; Mockito just doesn't
                                               // match the getter and setter.
```

To override those default values, [stub using `when` and `thenReturn` statements](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2). You can use as many as you like, and `thenReturn` accepts as many parameters as you'd like. The last value will be repeated indefinitely.

```
YourBean bean = Mockito.mock(YourBean.class);  // A mock acting like YourBean.
when(bean.getIntegerValue())
    .thenReturn(1)                             // Calls to getIntegerValue()
    .thenReturn(3, 5)                          // in sequence will return
    .thenReturn(7);                            // (1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7...).
```

**This also works for your simple case to stub `null` instead of 0:**

```
YourBean bean = Mockito.mock(YourBean.class);
when(bean.getIntegerValue()).thenReturn(null);
```

Note that the only way to make `getIntegerValue` return the value most recently set using `setIntegerValue` is to [write Answers](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11), which is tricky and verbose. This is part of the reason mocking data objects makes little sense: The logic to make a mock bean is complicated, where the use of a real bean is simple and authentic to your test.

Comment: Great answer about the downsides to getting overly attached to mocking.